# Calculate a 32-bit CRC lookup table in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, lookup-tables, crc32

I want to calculate a 32-bit CRC lookup table. One way I tried is by using the following code from [this website](http://www.barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/CRC-Calculation-C-Code):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

void make_crc_table()
{
    unsigned long POLYNOMIAL = 0x04c11db7;
    unsigned long WIDTH = 8 * sizeof(unsigned long);
    unsigned long TOPBIT = 1 << (WIDTH - 1);
    unsigned long crcTable[256];
    unsigned long remainder;
    // Compute the remainder of each possible dividend
    for (int dividend = 0; dividend < 256; ++dividend)
    {
        // Start with the dividend followed by zeros
        remainder = dividend << (WIDTH - 8);

        // Perform modulo-2 division, a bit at a time
        for (unsigned long bit = 8; bit > 0; --bit)
        {
            // Try to divide the current data bit
            if (remainder & TOPBIT)
            {
                remainder = (remainder << 1) ^ POLYNOMIAL;
            }
            else
            {
                remainder = (remainder << 1);
            }
        }
        crcTable[dividend] = remainder;
    }

    // Print the CRC table
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        if (i % 4 == 0)
        {
            std::cout <<"\n";
        }
        std::cout << std::hex << crcTable[i];
        std::cout << ", ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    make_crc_table();
    return 0;
}
```

Another way I tried is by using the following code that I found from [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22693578/crc-16-ccitt-with-lookup-table), and the code can be downloaded [from here in a file called CRC Calculator.zip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/crccalculator/files/CRC/)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

#define POLYNOMIAL      0x04C11DB7
uint32_t A_crcLookupTable[256] = {0};
#define WIDTH    (8 * sizeof(uint32_t))
#define TOPBIT   (((uint32_t)1) << (WIDTH - 1))

#define FP_reflect_DATA(_DATO)                      (_DATO)
#define FP_reflect_CRCTableValue(_CRCTableValue)    (_CRCTableValue)

uint32_t F_CRC_ObtenValorDeTabla(uint8_t VP_Pos_Tabla)
{
    uint32_t VP_CRCTableValue = 0;
    uint8_t VP_Pos_bit = 0;

    VP_CRCTableValue = ((uint32_t) FP_reflect_DATA(VP_Pos_Tabla)) << (WIDTH - 8);

    for (VP_Pos_bit = 0; VP_Pos_bit < 8; VP_Pos_bit++)
    {
        if (VP_CRCTableValue & TOPBIT)
        {
            VP_CRCTableValue = (VP_CRCTableValue << 1) ^ POLYNOMIAL;
        }
        else
        {
            VP_CRCTableValue = (VP_CRCTableValue << 1);
        }
    }
    return (FP_reflect_CRCTableValue(VP_CRCTableValue));
}

void F_CRC_InicializaTabla(void)
{
    uint16_t VP_Pos_Array = 0;

    for (VP_Pos_Array = 0; VP_Pos_Array < 256; VP_Pos_Array++)
    {
        A_crcLookupTable[VP_Pos_Array] = F_CRC_ObtenValorDeTabla((uint8_t)(VP_Pos_Array &0xFF));

    }

}


void make_crc_table()
{
    F_CRC_InicializaTabla();

    // Print the CRC table
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        if (i % 4 == 0)
        {
            std::cout <<"\n";
        }
        std::cout << std::hex << A_crcLookupTable[i];
        std::cout << ", ";
    }
}

int main()
{
    make_crc_table();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is what the **correct** final table should be, based on [this link](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Mathematics/CRC.htm):

```
// The constants here are for the CRC-32 generator 
// polynomial, as defined in the Microsoft 
// Systems Journal, March 1995, pp. 107-108
CONST
  table: ARRAY[0..255] OF DWORD =
 ($00000000, $77073096, $EE0E612C, $990951BA,
  $076DC419, $706AF48F, $E963A535, $9E6495A3,
  $0EDB8832, $79DCB8A4, $E0D5E91E, $97D2D988,
  $09B64C2B, $7EB17CBD, $E7B82D07, $90BF1D91,
  $1DB71064, $6AB020F2, $F3B97148, $84BE41DE,
  $1ADAD47D, $6DDDE4EB, $F4D4B551, $83D385C7,
  $136C9856, $646BA8C0, $FD62F97A, $8A65C9EC,
  $14015C4F, $63066CD9, $FA0F3D63, $8D080DF5,
  $3B6E20C8, $4C69105E, $D56041E4, $A2677172,
  $3C03E4D1, $4B04D447, $D20D85FD, $A50AB56B,
  $35B5A8FA, $42B2986C, $DBBBC9D6, $ACBCF940,
  $32D86CE3, $45DF5C75, $DCD60DCF, $ABD13D59,
  $26D930AC, $51DE003A, $C8D75180, $BFD06116,
  $21B4F4B5, $56B3C423, $CFBA9599, $B8BDA50F,
  $2802B89E, $5F058808, $C60CD9B2, $B10BE924,
  $2F6F7C87, $58684C11, $C1611DAB, $B6662D3D,

  $76DC4190, $01DB7106, $98D220BC, $EFD5102A,
  $71B18589, $06B6B51F, $9FBFE4A5, $E8B8D433,
  $7807C9A2, $0F00F934, $9609A88E, $E10E9818,
  $7F6A0DBB, $086D3D2D, $91646C97, $E6635C01,
  $6B6B51F4, $1C6C6162, $856530D8, $F262004E,
  $6C0695ED, $1B01A57B, $8208F4C1, $F50FC457,
  $65B0D9C6, $12B7E950, $8BBEB8EA, $FCB9887C,
  $62DD1DDF, $15DA2D49, $8CD37CF3, $FBD44C65,
  $4DB26158, $3AB551CE, $A3BC0074, $D4BB30E2,
  $4ADFA541, $3DD895D7, $A4D1C46D, $D3D6F4FB,
  $4369E96A, $346ED9FC, $AD678846, $DA60B8D0,
  $44042D73, $33031DE5, $AA0A4C5F, $DD0D7CC9,
  $5005713C, $270241AA, $BE0B1010, $C90C2086,
  $5768B525, $206F85B3, $B966D409, $CE61E49F,
  $5EDEF90E, $29D9C998, $B0D09822, $C7D7A8B4,
  $59B33D17, $2EB40D81, $B7BD5C3B, $C0BA6CAD,

  $EDB88320, $9ABFB3B6, $03B6E20C, $74B1D29A,
  $EAD54739, $9DD277AF, $04DB2615, $73DC1683,
  $E3630B12, $94643B84, $0D6D6A3E, $7A6A5AA8,
  $E40ECF0B, $9309FF9D, $0A00AE27, $7D079EB1,
  $F00F9344, $8708A3D2, $1E01F268, $6906C2FE,
  $F762575D, $806567CB, $196C3671, $6E6B06E7,
  $FED41B76, $89D32BE0, $10DA7A5A, $67DD4ACC,
  $F9B9DF6F, $8EBEEFF9, $17B7BE43, $60B08ED5,
  $D6D6A3E8, $A1D1937E, $38D8C2C4, $4FDFF252,
  $D1BB67F1, $A6BC5767, $3FB506DD, $48B2364B,
  $D80D2BDA, $AF0A1B4C, $36034AF6, $41047A60,
  $DF60EFC3, $A867DF55, $316E8EEF, $4669BE79,
  $CB61B38C, $BC66831A, $256FD2A0, $5268E236,
  $CC0C7795, $BB0B4703, $220216B9, $5505262F,
  $C5BA3BBE, $B2BD0B28, $2BB45A92, $5CB36A04,
  $C2D7FFA7, $B5D0CF31, $2CD99E8B, $5BDEAE1D,

  $9B64C2B0, $EC63F226, $756AA39C, $026D930A,
  $9C0906A9, $EB0E363F, $72076785, $05005713,
  $95BF4A82, $E2B87A14, $7BB12BAE, $0CB61B38,
  $92D28E9B, $E5D5BE0D, $7CDCEFB7, $0BDBDF21,
  $86D3D2D4, $F1D4E242, $68DDB3F8, $1FDA836E,
  $81BE16CD, $F6B9265B, $6FB077E1, $18B74777,
  $88085AE6, $FF0F6A70, $66063BCA, $11010B5C,
  $8F659EFF, $F862AE69, $616BFFD3, $166CCF45,
  $A00AE278, $D70DD2EE, $4E048354, $3903B3C2,
  $A7672661, $D06016F7, $4969474D, $3E6E77DB,
  $AED16A4A, $D9D65ADC, $40DF0B66, $37D83BF0,
  $A9BCAE53, $DEBB9EC5, $47B2CF7F, $30B5FFE9,
  $BDBDF21C, $CABAC28A, $53B39330, $24B4A3A6,
  $BAD03605, $CDD70693, $54DE5729, $23D967BF,
  $B3667A2E, $C4614AB8, $5D681B02, $2A6F2B94,
  $B40BBE37, $C30C8EA1, $5A05DF1B, $2D02EF8D);
```

However, this is what my output is from both programs (I diffed the output, and it's the same for both of them), and it's **incorrect**:

```
0, 4c11db7, 9823b6e, d4326d9, 
130476dc, 17c56b6b, 1a864db2, 1e475005, 
2608edb8, 22c9f00f, 2f8ad6d6, 2b4bcb61, 
350c9b64, 31cd86d3, 3c8ea00a, 384fbdbd, 
4c11db70, 48d0c6c7, 4593e01e, 4152fda9, 
5f15adac, 5bd4b01b, 569796c2, 52568b75, 
6a1936c8, 6ed82b7f, 639b0da6, 675a1011, 
791d4014, 7ddc5da3, 709f7b7a, 745e66cd, 
9823b6e0, 9ce2ab57, 91a18d8e, 95609039, 
8b27c03c, 8fe6dd8b, 82a5fb52, 8664e6e5, 
be2b5b58, baea46ef, b7a96036, b3687d81, 
ad2f2d84, a9ee3033, a4ad16ea, a06c0b5d, 
d4326d90, d0f37027, ddb056fe, d9714b49, 
c7361b4c, c3f706fb, ceb42022, ca753d95, 
f23a8028, f6fb9d9f, fbb8bb46, ff79a6f1, 
e13ef6f4, e5ffeb43, e8bccd9a, ec7dd02d, 
34867077, 30476dc0, 3d044b19, 39c556ae, 
278206ab, 23431b1c, 2e003dc5, 2ac12072, 
128e9dcf, 164f8078, 1b0ca6a1, 1fcdbb16, 
18aeb13, 54bf6a4, 808d07d, cc9cdca, 
7897ab07, 7c56b6b0, 71159069, 75d48dde, 
6b93dddb, 6f52c06c, 6211e6b5, 66d0fb02, 
5e9f46bf, 5a5e5b08, 571d7dd1, 53dc6066, 
4d9b3063, 495a2dd4, 44190b0d, 40d816ba, 
aca5c697, a864db20, a527fdf9, a1e6e04e, 
bfa1b04b, bb60adfc, b6238b25, b2e29692, 
8aad2b2f, 8e6c3698, 832f1041, 87ee0df6, 
99a95df3, 9d684044, 902b669d, 94ea7b2a, 
e0b41de7, e4750050, e9362689, edf73b3e, 
f3b06b3b, f771768c, fa325055, fef34de2, 
c6bcf05f, c27dede8, cf3ecb31, cbffd686, 
d5b88683, d1799b34, dc3abded, d8fba05a, 
690ce0ee, 6dcdfd59, 608edb80, 644fc637, 
7a089632, 7ec98b85, 738aad5c, 774bb0eb, 
4f040d56, 4bc510e1, 46863638, 42472b8f, 
5c007b8a, 58c1663d, 558240e4, 51435d53, 
251d3b9e, 21dc2629, 2c9f00f0, 285e1d47, 
36194d42, 32d850f5, 3f9b762c, 3b5a6b9b, 
315d626, 7d4cb91, a97ed48, e56f0ff, 
1011a0fa, 14d0bd4d, 19939b94, 1d528623, 
f12f560e, f5ee4bb9, f8ad6d60, fc6c70d7, 
e22b20d2, e6ea3d65, eba91bbc, ef68060b, 
d727bbb6, d3e6a601, dea580d8, da649d6f, 
c423cd6a, c0e2d0dd, cda1f604, c960ebb3, 
bd3e8d7e, b9ff90c9, b4bcb610, b07daba7, 
ae3afba2, aafbe615, a7b8c0cc, a379dd7b, 
9b3660c6, 9ff77d71, 92b45ba8, 9675461f, 
8832161a, 8cf30bad, 81b02d74, 857130c3, 
5d8a9099, 594b8d2e, 5408abf7, 50c9b640, 
4e8ee645, 4a4ffbf2, 470cdd2b, 43cdc09c, 
7b827d21, 7f436096, 7200464f, 76c15bf8, 
68860bfd, 6c47164a, 61043093, 65c52d24, 
119b4be9, 155a565e, 18197087, 1cd86d30, 
29f3d35, 65e2082, b1d065b, fdc1bec, 
3793a651, 3352bbe6, 3e119d3f, 3ad08088, 
2497d08d, 2056cd3a, 2d15ebe3, 29d4f654, 
c5a92679, c1683bce, cc2b1d17, c8ea00a0, 
d6ad50a5, d26c4d12, df2f6bcb, dbee767c, 
e3a1cbc1, e760d676, ea23f0af, eee2ed18, 
f0a5bd1d, f464a0aa, f9278673, fde69bc4, 
89b8fd09, 8d79e0be, 803ac667, 84fbdbd0, 
9abc8bd5, 9e7d9662, 933eb0bb, 97ffad0c, 
afb010b1, ab710d06, a6322bdf, a2f33668, 
bcb4666d, b8757bda, b5365d03, b1f740b4,
```

Comment: Are you using the same generator polynomial as the people you're checking your table against?

Comment: @genisage Yes, I am. I am using the CRC-32 polynomial that's used for Ethernet. Here it is, listed from the website where I got the output from: x32 + x26 + x23 + x22 + x16 + x12 + x11 + 
x10 + x8 + x7 + x5 + x4 + x2 + x1 + 1

Comment: Printing five columns of output makes it *really hard* to find the interesting coefficients.  Please use a power of two.

Comment: Is it possible that they represented it with the highest power as the most significant bit and you did it with the highest power as the least significant bit?

Comment: @genisage: I think that's the difference, both in the bit-order of the CRC values, and the bit-order of the array indexes.  Can't construct one table from the other, though, because the bit shifts are effectively performed in the wrong direction as well.

Comment: As 64-bit `long` is prevelent these days as well as selected processors using 16-bit `int`, best to use _exact_ width integers for this sort of code.  `uint32_t, uint16_t and uint8_t`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The bits are reversed. Note that the table entry for `array[0x80]` (0x80 is 0x01 reversed) `= 0xEDB88320`, which is `0x04C11DB7` reversed.

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

void make_crc_table(unsigned long crcTable[]) {
    unsigned long POLYNOMIAL = 0xEDB88320;
    unsigned long remainder;
    unsigned char b = 0;
    do {
        // Start with the data byte
        remainder = b;
        for (unsigned long bit = 8; bit > 0; --bit) {
            if (remainder & 1)
                remainder = (remainder >> 1) ^ POLYNOMIAL;
            else
                remainder = (remainder >> 1);
        }
        crcTable[(size_t)b] = remainder;
    } while(0 != ++b);
}

unsigned long gen_crc(unsigned char *p, size_t n, unsigned long crcTable[]) {
    unsigned long crc = 0xfffffffful;
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        crc = crcTable[*p++ ^ (crc&0xff)] ^ (crc>>8);
    return(~crc);
}

int main() {
    unsigned long crcTable[256];
    make_crc_table(crcTable);
    // Print the CRC table
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(8) << std::hex << crcTable[i];
        if (i % 4 == 3)
            std::cout << std::endl;
        else
            std::cout << ", ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see that value in the "correct" table, but I'm not sure how to correct the algorithms. Reversing the polynomial and using 0xEDB88320 didn't seem to work. Which bits should I reverse?

Comment: @Programmer_D - I updated the answer with example code.

Comment: @Programmer_D - follow up, with the one's complement of crc (~crc), then if you append that crc to the data, (little endian, so on X86, *(unsigned long *)(array+n) = crc ), then if you reencode using gen_crc(array, n+4, crcTable), the crc will be 0x2144df1c if there are no errors in the data. After a reencode, you can use crc ^= 0x2144df1c; to remove the effect of ~crc used in gen_crc.

Comment: It seems like the gen_crc implementation is wrong. Looking at the wiki page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) the lookup value should be first ((CRC ^ byte) & 0xFF), not (byte ^ (CRC&0xFF)).

Comment: @TypeKazt - in this case, the order of operations doesn't matter, since p is a pointer to a byte (unsigned char). In either case, ((CRC ^ byte)&0xff) or (byte ^ (CRC&0xff)), the result is the same, an 8 bit index that is promoted to a 32 bit index with leading zero bits since it is used as an index to the table (the xor operation also promotes to a 32 bit index with leading zero bits in the second case)

Comment: To calculate the CRC, (simple CRC calculation) is this enough? `CRC ^= 0x741B8CD7` or we need something more?

Comment: @Arash - where did you get the 741B8CD7 from? Sorry for the late response, I seem to missing some notifications.

Comment: @rcgldr Can I ask you a quick question, please? It might not be related. Which one is recommended, why? Encode data with two 32-bit CRCs (with different polynomials) or a 64-bit CRC?

Comment: @Arash - depends on the amount of data and the probability of bit errors. There is a 32 bit CRC guaranteed to detect up to 5 error bits with 32767 bits of data + crc. There is a 64 bit CRC guaranteed to detect up to 5 error bits with 65535 bits of data + crc. Finding a 64 bit CRC that handles 5 or more error bits takes a long time, so there aren't a lot of 64 bit CRC. If the data is larger, like 128k + bits, then it doesn't matter, the probability of not detecting an error is about 1 in 2^64 using two 32 bit CRC's or one 64 bit CRC.

Comment: @rcgldr Thank you. and for the last one, is calculating 64bit CRC more complex (or time-consuming) than 32bit CRC? (is there any computational benefit to use 64 over two 32bits?)

Comment: @Arash - for a processor with 64 bit registers, then a typical CRC calculation would be faster with one 64 bit CRC than two 32 bit CRCs.

Comment: @rcgldr Thank you so much for all your help. could you please give me some references? (I want to know why it's that way?)

Comment: @Arash - Here is a collection of 16, 32, and 64 bit [CRC examples](https://github.com/jeffareid/crc). Look at the ??????c.cpp source files for typical CRC implementations. The assembly (.asm) files are versions of [github Intel CRC examples](https://github.com/intel/isa-l/tree/master/crc)  modified to run with Visual Studio, with comments added for the RK?? constants (the Intel files are missing some comments). The ??????g.cpp source files are used to generate the RK?? constants.

Comment: @Arash -  the assembly files implementation is explained in [Intel - CRC using PCLMULQDQ pdf](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/fast-crc-computation-generic-polynomials-pclmulqdq-paper.pdf) . Note that my assembly examples do not include the variations with ZMM registers, as those are only available on some Intel processors with [AVX512](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVX-512), which I don't have.

Answer (score 4):

If there is not enough Flash and RAM (embedded software), you can use this function:

```
uint32_t CRC32_function(uint8_t *buf, uint32_t len){

    uint32_t val, crc;
    uint8_t i;

    crc = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    while(len--){
        val=(crc^*buf++)&0xFF;
        for(i=0; i<8; i++){
            val = val & 1 ? (val>>1)^0xEDB88320 : val>>1;
        }
        crc = val^crc>>8;
    }
    return crc^0xFFFFFFFF;
}
```

But CRC calculation takes more time.

Comment: can you explain the code? `val = val & 1 ? (val>>1)^0xEDB88320 : val>>1;`

Answer (score 0):

Table generation:

```
template <typename T, size_t max_size>
consteval std::array<T, max_size> genCRCTable(T magic_number) noexcept
{
    return [&](){
        std::array<T, max_size> crc_table;

        for(T index {}; auto&& elem : crc_table)
        {
            T remainder { index };
            for (int bit{}; bit < 8; ++bit)
                remainder = (remainder >> 1) ^ (remainder & 1 ? magic_number : 0);

            elem = remainder;
            ++index;
        }
        return crc_table;
    }();
}
```

Table print:

```
template <typename T, size_t max_size>
void printCRCTable(const std::array<T, max_size>& crc_table) noexcept
{
    constexpr size_t tsize { sizeof(T) };
    constexpr size_t width { tsize * 2 };
    constexpr size_t max_count_elem_in_line { 16 / tsize };

    auto flags { std::cout.flags() };
    std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::hex;

    for(size_t i{}; auto&& elem : crc_table)
    {
        std::cout << std::setw(width) 
                  << (tsize == 1 ? static_cast<int>(elem) : elem) 
                  << ((++i % max_count_elem_in_line)  == 0 ? "\n" : " ");
    }
    std::cout.flags(flags);

    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Main test uint32_t:

```
int main()
{
    using crc_type = uint32_t;
    constexpr size_t table_size { 64 };
    constexpr size_t magic_number { 0xEDB88320 };
    auto crc_table { genCRCTable<crc_type , table_size >( magic_number ) };
    
    printCRCTable(crc_table);
}
```

//--------------------------------------------------------

```
00000000 77073096 ee0e612c 990951ba
076dc419 706af48f e963a535 9e6495a3
0edb8832 79dcb8a4 e0d5e91e 97d2d988
09b64c2b 7eb17cbd e7b82d07 90bf1d91
1db71064 6ab020f2 f3b97148 84be41de
1adad47d 6ddde4eb f4d4b551 83d385c7
136c9856 646ba8c0 fd62f97a 8a65c9ec
14015c4f 63066cd9 fa0f3d63 8d080df5
3b6e20c8 4c69105e d56041e4 a2677172
3c03e4d1 4b04d447 d20d85fd a50ab56b
35b5a8fa 42b2986c dbbbc9d6 acbcf940
32d86ce3 45df5c75 dcd60dcf abd13d59
26d930ac 51de003a c8d75180 bfd06116
21b4f4b5 56b3c423 cfba9599 b8bda50f
2802b89e 5f058808 c60cd9b2 b10be924
2f6f7c87 58684c11 c1611dab b6662d3d
```

//---------------------------------------------------------

Main test uint16_t:

```
int main()
{
    using crc_type = uint16_t;
    constexpr size_t table_size { 64 };
    constexpr size_t magic_number { 0xEDB8 };
    auto crc_table { genCRCTable<crc_type , table_size >( magic_number ) };
    
    printCRCTable(crc_table);
}
```

//-----------------------------------------------

```
0000 51de a3bc f262 9c09 cdd7 3fb5 6e6b
e363 b2bd 40df 1101 7f6a 2eb4 dcd6 8d08
1db7 4c69 be0b efd5 81be d060 2202 73dc
fed4 af0a 5d68 0cb6 62dd 3303 c161 90bf
3b6e 6ab0 98d2 c90c a767 f6b9 04db 5505
d80d 89d3 7bb1 2a6f 4404 15da e7b8 b666
26d9 7707 8565 d4bb bad0 eb0e 196c 48b2
c5ba 9464 6606 37d8 59b3 086d fa0f abd1
```

//------------------------------------------------

Main test uint8_t:

```
int main()
{
    using crc_type = uint8_t;
    constexpr size_t table_size { 64 };
    constexpr size_t magic_number { 0xED };
    auto crc_table { genCRCTable<crc_type , table_size >( magic_number ) };
    
    printCRCTable(crc_table);
}
```

//-----------------------------------------------

```
00 05 0a 0f 14 11 1e 1b 28 2d 22 27 3c 39 36 33
50 55 5a 5f 44 41 4e 4b 78 7d 72 77 6c 69 66 63
a0 a5 aa af b4 b1 be bb 88 8d 82 87 9c 99 96 93
f0 f5 fa ff e4 e1 ee eb d8 dd d2 d7 cc c9 c6 c3
```